# Turning a single radian value into a Vector Direction

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working in XNA.

I have a float value called "Rotation". It goes from -3.14 to 3.14. It specifies the rotation of a sprite.

I want to use this value to produce a Vector with values for rotation on the X and Y axis.

For instance, if the sprite is turned directly to the right, i want to get the value (1, 0).

If it's turned directly upwards, i want (0, -1). You get the picture.

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use sine and cosine:

```
( Math.Cos(rotation), Math.Sin(rotation) )
```

Comment: Well hey, that was easy. Thanks a lot, learned something new today!